# How can I connect to a MAC bluetooth address from an Flutter Android App

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, mac-address

I am working on a Flutter app to connect to a specific Linux computer via Bluetooth. I am able to perform this action easily on the terminal using the following command:

```
sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 d4:25:8b:72:28:01 1 &
```

I am trying to perform the same on the app as follows:

```
var shell = Shell();
await shell.run('''
    sudo killall rfcomm

    sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 d4:25:8b:72:28:01 1 &

     ''');
```

But I can not see any connection on the target Linux machine as it is listening:

```
sudo rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 1
Waiting for connection on channel 1
```

How can I perform this operation (using Shell commands or any other way) in the Flutter app?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you solved the problem with the connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a way to use Bluetooth on Flutter, how about using a package for it? For example, you might find [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) useful for your purpose.

Comment: Yes I have tried this package with an example project. The problem is that my mac address is: d4:25:8b:72:28:01 but when I install and run test project, I scan and discover the device address as d4:25:8b:72:28:05. 
Besides that, when using that package, when I try to, I can not have a successful connection.